# Pan and Zoom Image Plugin

Tags: jquery, angular, image, imageview

I am trying to implement something like google arts and culture image zoom and pan.

[Look here for example.](https://artsandculture.google.com/asset/energ%C3%ADa-transformadora-p%C3%A9rez-celis/YwEWlJqpbEsoVg)

I tried working with [ng2-image-viewer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-image-viewer) library but can't seem to be able to work it out.

Following is the snippet i tried.

```
<app-image-viewer 
[images]="['https://images.nga.gov/en/web_images/niagara2.jpg']"
[loadOnInit]="true"
[idContainer]="'idOnHTML'">
</app-image-viewer>
```

Result:

[image]

As you can see, image is above the expected area, not proper controls and neither is that small rectangle that gives us the minimap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this:

1- To install this library, run:

```
npm install iv-viewer
npm install ng2-image-viewer
```

2- in AppModule

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

// Import your library
import { ImageViewerModule } from 'ng2-image-viewer';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,

    // Specify your library as an import
    ImageViewerModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

3- Now just add the these codes on your angular-cli.json file:

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/ng2-image-viewer/imageviewer.scss"
],
```

4- Once your library is imported, you can use its components, directives and pipes in your Angular application:

```
<!-- You can now use your library component in app.component.html -->
<h1>
  Image Viewer
</h1>
<app-image-viewer [images]="['https://picsum.photos/900/500/?random', 'https://picsum.photos/900/500/?random', 'https://picsum.photos/900/500/?random']"
[idContainer]="'idOnHTML'"
[loadOnInit]="true"></app-image-viewer>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng2-image-viewer?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Done, now i'm facing an issue, look at the question.

Comment: did you add styles file? because in my project it doesn't look like yours

Comment: can you make a live demo?

Comment: https://github.com/mercurial-providence/app-angular-gallery.git Please.

Comment: I am testing this plugin in `localhost:4200/paste` route.

Comment: I found it. problem is in angular.json. you added style into `test` project (line 103) but also you have to add it to `app-ang` (line 31)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200669/discussion-between-miladfm-and-mercurial).